# convert string to hash using libXML in perl

Tags: xml, perl

I have a string in xml format and I wish to convert it to a hash using LIBXML.
How can I do so in perl?

Comment: What format should the hash have? (And if you don't care, why does it have to be a hash?)

Comment: XML Hash might be your best bet: http://search.cpan.org/~braceta/XML-Hash-0.95/lib/XML/Hash.pm (when in doubt of how to do something like this in perl there is a really good chance a module exists in cpan)

Answer (score 3):

[Searching](https://metacpan.org/search?q=dist%3AXML-LibXML&q=hash) the [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/release/XML-LibXML) distribution, it seems that support for such functionality is limited to attributes only via [`XML::LibXML::AttributeHash`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aAttributeHash).

To quote [`XML::LibXML::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aDOM):

> One also has to remember, that `XML::LibXML` is an interface to libxml2
>   nodes which actually reside on the C-Level of `XML::LibXML`. This means
>   each node is a reference to a structure different than a perl hash or
>   array. The only way to access these structure's values is through the
>   DOM interface provided by `XML::LibXML`. This also means, that one
>   *can't* simply inherit an `XML::LibXML` node and add new member variables as they were hash keys.

There are, however, a ton of [other](https://metacpan.org/search?q=xml+hash) [modules](https://metacpan.org/search?q=xml+tie+hash) that can hashify XML strings:

- [`XML::Hash`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aHash)
- [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig)
- [`XML::Fast`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aFast)
- [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSimple)
- [`XML::Smart`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSmart)

Answer (score 1):

[XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML) has a perfectly good DOM interface, but if you want to "convert to a hash" you'll either need to do some DOM traversal yourself to smoosh the data into a hash in the format you want, or use something like [XML::Simple](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aSimple) instead of libxml. XML::Simple is kind of horrible for reliable interoperation, but sometimes it's the easiest thing.